# Show different unread mail for my inbox and my folder in thunderbird

Tags: macos, thunderbird

I want my thunderbird in my dock show all of my unread mail (prefer show it separated) somthing like DockStar for Mail.app:

[image]

I use gmail filter so some of my mail skip inbox and just get proper label and my thunderbird show them in the folder:

[image]

My problem is that my thunderbird just notify me of my unread mail in my inbox and if I have many mail in folder that is new until I open thunderbird windows I don't notify of them:

[image]

are there any solution for this problem?